# Enable VR mode flips ViewCube

Tags: autodesk-forge, webvr, autodesk-viewer

The ViewCube flips so that bottom side of the ViewCube is up, once I click the 'Enable VR Mode' button from menu. The model stays the right side up, but the ViewCube flips.

If I compare to this example http://viewervr.herokuapp.com/, seems that the ViewCube stays correctly.

I am loading the WebVR extension as follows:

```
public initialize(): void {
   const options = {
      'env': 'AutodeskProduction',
      'getAccessToken': this.getToken,
      'refreshToken': this.getToken
   };
   const element = document.getElementById(this.id);
   this.viewer = new avp.GuiViewer3D(element);

   av.Initializer(
   options,
   () => {
      this.viewer.initialize();
      this.initiliazeDefaultSettings();
      this.initiliazeEventListeners();                    
      this.loadDocument(this.urn);
      this.viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.WebVR');
   });
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: I do not think this is related to the way loading WebVR extension, may be related to your model, do you have a link that I can check?

Comment: It seems that this is due to the model being an IFC model. I tried a couple of examples from vrok it (Robot Arm and House), and they seem to work. Here is an example of an IFC file you try [link](http://openifcmodel.cs.auckland.ac.nz/Model/Details/110). Is there any way to fix this? So the view cube would not flip? @Zhong